# Unable to scrape text using Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to automate acquiring data for a research project from Morningstar using Selenium and BeautifulSoup in Python. I am quite new in Python so I have just tried a bunch of solutions from Stackoverflow and similar fora, but I have been unsuccessful.

What I am trying to scrape is on the url https://www.morningstar.dk/dk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000014CU8&tab=3
In the url, I am specifically looking for the "Faktorprofil" for which you can click to show the data as a table. I can get the headings from the url, but I am unable to soup.find any other text. I have tried using multiple ids and classes, but without any luck. The code I believe I have been the most successful with is written below.
I hope someone can help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument(" --headless")



chrome_driver = os.getcwd() +"/chromedriver"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=chrome_driver)


driver.get("https://www.morningstar.dk/dk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000ZG2E&tab=3")


soup_file=driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_file, 'html.parser')

print(soup.title.get_text())

#print(soup.find(class_='').get_text())
#print(soup.find(id='').get_text())
```

This is the data I want to scrape
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkSMj.png

Comment: I can do this in Selenium, let me know if you are ready to accept solution in Selenium

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I am very interested in a solution in Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those tables are in an `iframe`. Below code will retrieve the data and prints as a list.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.morningstar.dk/dk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000014CU8&tab=3")
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'show-table')]//span").click()
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'sal-mip-factor-profile__value-table')]/table//tr/th")
header = []
for tab in table:
    header.append(tab.text)
print(header)
tablebody = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'sal-mip-factor-profile__value-table')]/table//tbody/tr")
for tab in tablebody:
    data = []
    content = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    for con in content:
        data.append(con.text)
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
['Faktorer', 'Fonds værdi', '5 år Min. Værdi', '5 år Maks værdi', 'Kategori Gennemsnitlig']
['Stil', '62,33', '31,52', '76,36', '48,20']
['Effektiv rente', '48,83', '20,82', '69,12', '34,74']
['Momentum', '58,47', '7,48', '77,21', '71,15']
['Kvalitet', '25,65', '21,61', '59,66', '38,15']
['Volatilitet', '45,25', '34,66', '81,08', '74,93']
['Likviditet', '35,70', '33,40', '74,94', '79,39']
['Størrelse', '39,60', '35,67', '48,78', '87,59']
```